# Get the line number of a tag in an XML document with Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what needs to be done in order to find the line number of a tag when parsing XML with Perl. It would be great if there's an existing module that can parse the XML into a hash that contains the line numbers of (a subset of) the tags, but I haven't stumbled across one yet.

I'd like to avoid having to deal with start_element, etc, but I have a feeling that's what I'm going to have to resort to.

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: The module `XML::Parser::Expat` has a method `current_line` that is self-explanatory. Without your code, input, output and so on, this could help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `XML::LibXML` module provides a [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0107/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) class which has a `line_number()` method. Example:

```
my $document = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => '<a><b></b></a>');
foreach my $node ($document->findnodes('//b')) {
    print $node->line_number(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: That actually looks like it might do what I need it to do. Thanks!

For anyone looking for help with this, give this link a shot: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=490846